# macOS no longer recognizes environment.plist

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, high-sierra, environment-variables

I need to set up environment variables for Pixar RenderMan Pro Server in macOS 10.13.

Yosemite, El Capitan, Sierra and High Sierra no longer recognize `environment.plist` located in a hidden `.MacOSX` directory:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH</key> 
        <string>/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5/lib</string> 
        <key>RMANTREE</key>
        <string>/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5</string> 
    </dict>
</plist>
```

At the present time I'm using `.bash_profile` to set up environment variables:

```
echo RenderManProServer environment variables are set...

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5/lib/
export RMANTREE=/Applications/Pixar/RenderManProServer-21.5/
```

> What else methods besides the described above allow Mac user to set up environment variables in macOS High Sierra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a system-wide setting, you can add a snippet to `/etc/profile` for all shells, or `/etc/bashrc` for just interactive Bash instances.